# Passing PHP value to AGI

Tags: php, html, asterisk

I'm still new to PHP and asterisk. I am trying to pass the value from an HTML text input to a php page which communicates with asterisk to send an sms text via GSM Modem. So far this is the code that I have experimented on.

```
     $num = $_POST['cNum'];
     $msg = $_POST['cMessage'];
     $type='gsm';
     $method='send';
     $sync='sync sms';
     $span='4';
     $destination=$num;
     $message=$msg;
     $timeout='20';
     $id='1234';
     $agi->Command("$type $method $sync $span $destination $message $timeout $id");
     exit(0);
```

This does work but the problem is for example I were to enter "Sample Space" to the text input "cMessage", the text message that I will receive will only be "Sample" (without the double quotation marks). All words after the first space character is omitted. However if I were to try and code it this way:

```
     $num = $_POST['cNum'];
     $msg = $_POST['cMessage'];
     $type='gsm';
     $method='send';
     $sync='sync sms';
     $span='4';
     $destination=$num;
     $message='"Sample Space"';   <----------- for example
     $timeout='20';
     $id='1234';
     $agi->Command("$type $method $sync $span $destination $message $timeout $id");
     exit(0);
```

I could receive the whole message "Sample Space" (without the double quotation marks)
Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams like you missed quotation when learned php.

Try use it

```
$message='\"Sample Space\"';   <----------- for example
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but what if I were to pass a value to $message through a variable for example $message=$msg;?

Comment: you have do same. doesn't metter how you pass. in resulting line it have be quoted

Comment: ahh yes I figured this one out yesterday. Thanks!